# Click event not binding to dynamically loaded element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this span loaded dynamically via ajax :

```
<span class="popup-exit" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe633;"></span>
```

It generally shows a cross icon which is absolute positioned and the jquery is as follows :

```
$(".screen-overlay").on(".popup-exit", "click", function() {
    alert("Hello");
    $(".screen-overlay").hide();
});
```

Its not working! Any suggestions?

Comment: No. screen-overlay has on more div in which everything gets loaded!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the `event` and `selector` mixed up

```
$(".screen-overlay").on("click", ".popup-exit", function() {
    alert("Hello");
    $(".screen-overlay").hide();
});
```

Comment: Damn! Guess i need some more Caffeine! :D
Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to but it says wait 6 more minutes before you accept an answer! I'll do that asap!